# ¿Descargar imagen desde el nombre guardado en la base de datos ajax Codeigniter?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Actualmente con un plugin subo la imagen a mi servidor, con este plugin(Dropzone.js) carturo la ruta de este archivo. todo esto lo hago para no tener que subir el archivo fisco a la base de datos y solo guardo el nombre.

Ejemplo subir archivo captura

```
var nameAdjunto  = "/var/www/html/cartoni/uploads/" +myDropzone.files[0].name;
alert(nameAdjunto);
```

> retorna /var/www/html/cartoni/uploads/captura.PNG

El valor nameAdjunto lo guardo en la base de datos

Ahora llamo a esa imagen

Modelo

```
public function listar($table)
    {
        $data= $this->db->get($table);
        return $data->result();
    }
```

controlador:

```
$data['uploads'] = $this->Model->listar('tabla_upload);
```

¿Como puedo descargar el archivo solo teniendo la ruta?

¿Como construyo la url para poder descargar el archivo ?

```
 <?php echo var_dump($uploads->name) ?>
```

Espero haberme explicado bien muchas gracias !

Answer (score 1):

Viendo en la documentación de codeigniter hay una [funcion helper](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/download_helper.html) llamada `force_download()` la cual recibe como parametros el nombre del archivo y el archivo. Si ya sabes la ruta del archivo solo debes pasar como primer parámetro y en su segundo parámetro pasas `null`:

`$this->load->helper('download'); //primero se carga el helper 
force_download('./uploads/captura.png',NULL);`

Esto funciona si tu archivo `index.php` se encuentra en la carpeta `/cartoni/`, codeigniter crea la ruta.